# Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, filtering

I want to filter my dataframe with an `or` condition to keep rows with a particular column's values that are outside the range `[-0.25, 0.25]`. I tried:

```
df = df[(df['col'] < -0.25) or (df['col'] > 0.25)]
```

But I get the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: use `|` instead of `or`

Comment: Here's a workaround: `abs(result['var'])>0.25`

Comment: Related: [Logical operators for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21415661/4909087)

Comment: I ran into the same error message using the standard `max()` function.  Replacing it with with `numpy.maximum()` for element-wise maxima between two values solved my problem.

Answer (score 1126, accepted):

The `or` and `and` Python statements require **truth**-values. For pandas, these are considered ambiguous, so you should use "bitwise" `|` (or) or `&` (and) operations:

```
df = df[(df['col'] < -0.25) | (df['col'] > 0.25)]
```

These are overloaded for these kinds of data structures to yield the element-wise `or` or `and`.

---

Just to add some more explanation to this statement:

The exception is thrown when you want to get the `bool` of a `pandas.Series`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.Series([1])
>>> bool(x)
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

You hit a place where the operator **implicitly** converted the operands to `bool` (you used `or` but it also happens for `and`, `if` and `while`):

```
>>> x or x
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> x and x
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> if x:
...     print('fun')
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> while x:
...     print('fun')
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Besides these four statements, there are several Python functions that hide some `bool` calls (like `any`, `all`, `filter`, ...). These are normally not problematic with `pandas.Series`, but for completeness I wanted to mention these.

---

In your case, the exception isn't really helpful, because it doesn't mention the **right alternatives**. For `and` and `or`, if you want element-wise comparisons, you can use:

- [`numpy.logical_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html):

  ```
  >>> import numpy as np
  >>> np.logical_or(x, y)
  ```

  or simply the `|` operator:

  ```
  >>> x | y
  ```
- [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

  ```
  >>> np.logical_and(x, y)
  ```

  or simply the `&` operator:

  ```
  >>> x & y
  ```

If you're using the operators, then be sure to set your parentheses correctly because of [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

There are [several logical NumPy functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html) which *should* work on `pandas.Series`.

---

The alternatives mentioned in the Exception are more suited if you encountered it when doing `if` or `while`. I'll shortly explain each of these:

- If you want to check if your Series is **empty**:

  ```
  >>> x = pd.Series([])
  >>> x.empty
  True
  >>> x = pd.Series([1])
  >>> x.empty
  False
  ```

  Python normally interprets the `len`gth of containers (like `list`, `tuple`, ...) as truth-value if it has no explicit Boolean interpretation. So if you want the Python-like check, you could do: `if x.size` or `if not x.empty` instead of `if x`.
- If your `Series` contains **one and only one** Boolean value:

  ```
  >>> x = pd.Series([100])
  >>> (x > 50).bool()
  True
  >>> (x < 50).bool()
  False
  ```
- If you want to check the **first and only item** of your Series (like `.bool()`, but it works even for non-Boolean contents):

  ```
  >>> x = pd.Series([100])
  >>> x.item()
  100
  ```
- If you want to check if **all** or **any** item is not-zero, not-empty or not-False:

  ```
  >>> x = pd.Series([0, 1, 2])
  >>> x.all()   # Because one element is zero
  False
  >>> x.any()   # because one (or more) elements are non-zero
  True
  ```

Answer (score 131):

Pandas uses bitwise `&` `|`. Also, each condition should be wrapped inside `( )`.

This works:

```
data_query = data[(data['year'] >= 2005) & (data['year'] <= 2010)]
```

But the same query without parentheses does not:

```
data_query = data[(data['year'] >= 2005 & data['year'] <= 2010)]
```

Comment: ***Why*** should each condition  be wrapped inside `( )`? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57897625/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). (But ****** ***without*** ****** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o/71956180#71956180) might provide the *why*.

Answer (score 64):

For Boolean logic, use `&` and `|`.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))

>>> df

          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863

>>> df.loc[(df.C > 0.25) | (df.C < -0.25)]

          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
```

To see what is happening, you get a column of Booleans for each comparison, e.g.,

```
df.C > 0.25

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: C, dtype: bool
```

When you have multiple criteria, you will get multiple columns returned.  This is why the join logic is ambiguous.  Using `and` or `or` treats each column separately, so you first need to reduce that column to a single Boolean value.  For example, to see if any value or all values in each of the columns is True.

```
# Any value in either column is True?
(df.C > 0.25).any() or (df.C < -0.25).any()

True

# All values in either column is True?
(df.C > 0.25).all() or (df.C < -0.25).all()

False
```

One convoluted way to achieve the same thing is to zip all of these columns together, and perform the appropriate logic.

```
>>> df[[any([a, b]) for a, b in zip(df.C > 0.25, df.C < -0.25)]]

          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
```

For more details, refer to [Boolean Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) in the documentation.

Answer (score 17):

This is quite a common question for beginners when making multiple conditions in Pandas. Generally speaking, there are two possible conditions causing this error:

**Condition 1: Python Operator Precedence**

There is a paragraph of [Boolean indexing | Indexing and selecting data — pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) explains this:

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the data. The operators are: `|` for `or`, `&` for `and`, and `~` for `not`. These **must** be grouped by using **parentheses**.
>
> By default Python will evaluate an expression such as `df['A'] > 2 & df['B'] < 3` as `df['A'] > (2 & df['B']) < 3`, while the desired evaluation order is `(df['A'] > 2) & (df['B'] < 3)`.

```py
# Wrong
df['col'] < -0.25 | df['col'] > 0.25

# Right
(df['col'] < -0.25) | (df['col'] > 0.25)
```

There are some possible ways to get rid off the parentheses, and I will cover this later.

---

**Condition 2: Improper Operator/Statement**

As is explained in the previous quotation, you need use `|` for `or`, `&` for `and`, and `~` for `not`.

```py
# Wrong
(df['col'] < -0.25) or (df['col'] > 0.25)

# Right
(df['col'] < -0.25) | (df['col'] > 0.25)
```

---

Another possible situation is that you are using a Boolean Series in an `if` statement.

```py
# Wrong
if pd.Series([True, False]):
    pass
```

It's clear that the Python `if` statement accepts Boolean-like expression rather than Pandas Series. You should use [`pandas.Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) or methods listed in the error message to convert the Series to a value according to your need.

For example:

```py
# Right
if df['col'].eq(0).all():
    # If you want all column values equal to zero
    print('do something')

# Right
if df['col'].eq(0).any():
    # If you want at least one column value equal to zero
    print('do something')
```

---

Let's talk about ways to escape the parentheses in the first situation.

1. **Use Pandas mathematical functions**

   Pandas has defined a lot of mathematical functions, including comparison, as follows:

   - [`pandas.Series.lt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for *less than*;
   - [`pandas.Series.gt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for *greater than*;
   - [`pandas.Series.le()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) for *less and equal*;
   - [`pandas.Series.ge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for *greater and equal*;
   - [`pandas.Series.ne()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for *not equal*;
   - [`pandas.Series.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for *equal*;

   As a result, you can use

   ```py
   df = df[(df['col'] < -0.25) | (df['col'] > 0.25)]

   # is equal to

   df = df[df['col'].lt(-0.25) | df['col'].gt(0.25)]
   ```
2. **Use [`pandas.Series.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html)**

   If you want to select rows in between two values, you can use `pandas.Series.between`:

   - `df['col].between(left, right)` is equal to 
     `(left <= df['col']) & (df['col'] <= right)`;
   - `df['col].between(left, right, inclusive='left)` is equal to 
     `(left <= df['col']) & (df['col'] < right)`;
   - `df['col].between(left, right, inclusive='right')` is equal to 
     `(left < df['col']) & (df['col'] <= right)`;
   - `df['col].between(left, right, inclusive='neither')` is equal to 
     `(left < df['col']) & (df['col'] < right)`;

   ```py
   df = df[(df['col'] > -0.25) & (df['col'] < 0.25)]

   # is equal to

   df = df[df['col'].between(-0.25, 0.25, inclusive='neither')]
   ```
3. **Use [`pandas.DataFrame.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)**

   Document referenced before has a chapter [The `query()` Method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#the-query-method) explains this well.

   `pandas.DataFrame.query()` can help you select a DataFrame with a condition string. Within the query string, you can use both bitwise operators (`&` and `|`) and their boolean cousins (`and` and `or`). Moreover, you can omit the parentheses, but I don't recommend it for readability reasons.

   ```py
   df = df[(df['col'] < -0.25) | (df['col'] > 0.25)]

   # is equal to

   df = df.query('col < -0.25 or col > 0.25')
   ```
4. **Use [`pandas.DataFrame.eval()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html)**

   `pandas.DataFrame.eval()` evaluates a string describing operations on DataFrame columns. Thus, we can use this method to build our multiple conditions. The syntax is the same with `pandas.DataFrame.query()`.

   ```py
   df = df[(df['col'] < -0.25) | (df['col'] > 0.25)]

   # is equal to

   df = df[df.eval('col < -0.25 or col > 0.25')]
   ```

   `pandas.DataFrame.query()` and `pandas.DataFrame.eval()` can do more things than I describe here. You are recommended to read their documentation and have fun with them.

Answer (score 15):

Or, alternatively, you could use the *operator* module. More detailed information is [in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

```
import operator
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))
df.loc[operator.or_(df.C > 0.25, df.C < -0.25)]

          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.4438
```

Comment: Operator helped me with problem in jinja.
Jinja doesn't accept & operator.. Pandas query can't reach jinja variable. But .loc with operator works! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922103/1878788) explains very well what is happening and provides a solution. I would like to add another solution that might be suitable in similar cases: using the [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
df = df.query("(col > 0.25) or (col < -0.25)")
```

See also *[Indexing and selecting data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-query)*.

(Some tests with a dataframe I'm currently working with suggest that this method is a bit slower than using the bitwise operators on series of Booleans: 2 ms vs. 870 µs)

**A piece of warning**: At least one situation where this is not straightforward is when column names happen to be Python expressions. I had columns named `WT_38hph_IP_2`, `WT_38hph_input_2` and `log2(WT_38hph_IP_2/WT_38hph_input_2)` and wanted to perform the following query: `"(log2(WT_38hph_IP_2/WT_38hph_input_2) > 1) and (WT_38hph_IP_2 > 20)"`

I obtained the following exception cascade:

- `KeyError: 'log2'`
- `UndefinedVariableError: name 'log2' is not defined`
- `ValueError: "log2" is not a supported function`

I guess this happened because the query parser was trying to make something from the first two columns instead of identifying the expression with the name of the third column.

A possible workaround is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083013/1878788).

Answer (score 4):

If you have more than one value:

```
df['col'].all()
```

If it’s only a single value:

```
df['col'].item()
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting an error in this command:

```
if df != '':
    pass
```

But it worked when I changed it to this:

```
if df is not '':
    pass
```

Comment: That is interesting, but it could be incidental. What is the explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use bitwise operators `|` instead of `or` and `&` instead of `and` in pandas. You can't simply use the bool statements from python.

For much complex filtering, create a `mask` and apply the mask on the dataframe. 
Put all your query in the mask and apply it. Suppose,

```
mask = (df["col1"]>=df["col2"]) & (stock["col1"]<=df["col2"])
df_new = df[mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give the benchmark of the three most common way (also mentioned above):

```py
from timeit import repeat

setup = """
import numpy as np;
import random;
x = np.linspace(0,100);
lb, ub = np.sort([random.random() * 100, random.random() * 100]).tolist()
"""
stmts = 'x[(x > lb) * (x <= ub)]', 'x[(x > lb) & (x <= ub)]', 'x[np.logical_and(x > lb, x <= ub)]'

for _ in range(3):
    for stmt in stmts:
        t = min(repeat(stmt, setup, number=100_000))
        print('%.4f' % t, stmt)
    print()
```

Result:

```
0.4808 x[(x > lb) * (x <= ub)]
0.4726 x[(x > lb) & (x <= ub)]
0.4904 x[np.logical_and(x > lb, x <= ub)]

0.4725 x[(x > lb) * (x <= ub)]
0.4806 x[(x > lb) & (x <= ub)]
0.5002 x[np.logical_and(x > lb, x <= ub)]

0.4781 x[(x > lb) * (x <= ub)]
0.4336 x[(x > lb) & (x <= ub)]
0.4974 x[np.logical_and(x > lb, x <= ub)]
```

But, `*` is not supported in Panda Series, and NumPy Array is faster than pandas data frame (around 1000 times slower, see number):

```py
from timeit import repeat

setup = """
import numpy as np;
import random;
import pandas as pd;
x = pd.DataFrame(np.linspace(0,100));
lb, ub = np.sort([random.random() * 100, random.random() * 100]).tolist()
"""
stmts = 'x[(x > lb) & (x <= ub)]', 'x[np.logical_and(x > lb, x <= ub)]'

for _ in range(3):
    for stmt in stmts:
        t = min(repeat(stmt, setup, number=100))
        print('%.4f' % t, stmt)
    print()
```

Result:

```
0.1964 x[(x > lb) & (x <= ub)]
0.1992 x[np.logical_and(x > lb, x <= ub)]

0.2018 x[(x > lb) & (x <= ub)]
0.1838 x[np.logical_and(x > lb, x <= ub)]

0.1871 x[(x > lb) & (x <= ub)]
0.1883 x[np.logical_and(x > lb, x <= ub)]
```

Note: adding one line of code `x = x.to_numpy()` will need about 20 µs.

For those who prefer `%timeit`:

```
import numpy as np
import random
lb, ub = np.sort([random.random() * 100, random.random() * 100]).tolist()
lb, ub
x = pd.DataFrame(np.linspace(0,100))

def asterik(x):
    x = x.to_numpy()
    return x[(x > lb) * (x <= ub)]

def and_symbol(x):
    x = x.to_numpy()
    return x[(x > lb) & (x <= ub)]

def numpy_logical(x):
    x = x.to_numpy()
    return x[np.logical_and(x > lb, x <= ub)]

for i in range(3):
    %timeit asterik(x)
    %timeit and_symbol(x)
    %timeit numpy_logical(x)
    print('\n')
```

Result:

```
23 µs ± 3.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
35.6 µs ± 9.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
31.3 µs ± 8.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)


21.4 µs ± 3.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
21.9 µs ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
21.7 µs ± 500 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)


25.1 µs ± 3.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
36.8 µs ± 18.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
28.2 µs ± 5.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue while working in the Panda dataframe.

I have used: [numpy.logical_and](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

Here I am trying to select the row with Id matched with `41d7853` and degreee_type not with `Certification`.

Like below:

```
display(df_degrees.loc[np.logical_and(df_degrees['person_id'] == '41d7853' , df_degrees['degree_type'] !='Certification')])
```

If I try to write code like the below:

```
display(df_degrees.loc[df_degrees['person_id'] == '41d7853' and df_degrees['degree_type'] !='Certification'])
```

We will get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have used [numpy.logical_and](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and got stalled with a [PySpark](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyspark/index.htm) dataframe for few days. ***I was able to resolve it successfully by filling na values with 0*** since I was comparing integer values from two fields.

Answer (score 0):

One minor thing, which wasted my time.

Put the conditions (if comparing using " = ", " != ") in parentheses. Failing to do so also raises this exception.

This will work:

```
df[(some condition) conditional operator (some conditions)]
```

This will not:

```
df[some condition conditional-operator some condition]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was having a type value error due to which this error was raising. Make sure the comparison operator been given the same datatype element to compare.