# Python and RSS feeds - parse feeder

Tags: python, parsing, rss, feed, feedparser

I'm using feed parser in python and I'm a beginner in python.

```
for post in d.entries:
    if test_word3 and test_word2 in post.title:
        print(post.title)
```

What I'm trying to do is make feed parser find a couple of words inside titles in the RSS feeds.

Comment: can you tell us what the INPUT is and what the OUTPUT should be?

Comment: Use `and`, not `&&`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485466/pythons-equivalent-of-in-an-if-statement

Answer (score 0):

Note that **and** does not distribute across the **in** operator.

```
if test_word3 in post.title and
   test_word2 in post.title:
```

should solve your problem.  What you wrote is evaluated as

```
if test_word3 and (test_word2 in post.title):
```

... and this turns into ...

```
if (test_word3 != "") and (test_word2 in post.title):
```

Simplifying a little ...
The Boolean value of a string is whether it's non-empty.
The Boolean value of an integer is whether it's non-zero.