# how to compare 2 columns of a 2d array at a time with columns of another array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I have two  string arrays each with three columns.I want to compare first two columns of both 2-d arrays(having 3 cols and 4000 rows). if they match then i need those matching values.But my code is not working.Here is a sample.

```
array1=["1stcolumn...", "2ndColumn...", "3rdColumn..."]
array2=[1stcolumn 2ndColumn 3rdColumn]
if (array1[0]==array2[0] and array1[1]==array2[1]):
       array3.append('matches: {!r}'.format(array1))
print(array3)
```

Comment: `...my code is not working` what is wrong with it? what does it print?

Comment: `&` would work if there were parenthesis around the equivalence tests.

Comment: @Wyatt in Python, lists are called lists, and arrays are called arrays. lists are not arrays.

Comment: it is printing complete array without matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

`if array1[:2] == array2[:2]:` compares all items from the index 0 to 2(2 is not included), and comes up with the same result as `if array1[0] == array2[0] and array1[1] == array2[1]:`. Also, it is simpler.(Thanks to **Wyatt** for comment)

If your arrays are 2-dimensional:

```
def compare_columns(array1, array2):
    if len(array1) != len(array2):
        return False # If row numbers are not same, return false

    for row_number in range(len(array1)):
        if array1[row_number][:2] != array2[row_number][:2]:
            return False # If the content is not equal, return false

    return True # All of the content is equal, the return true

# For example, these are 2-dimensional arrays
array1 = [["1.1", "1.2", "Lord of the Day of Judgment!"],
          ["2.1", "2.2", "Lord of the Day of Judgment!"]]
array2 = [["1.1", "1.2", "مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ"],
          ["2.1", "2.2", "مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ"]]

array3 = []       
if compare_columns(array1, array2):
       array3.append('matches: {!r}'.format(array1))
print(array3)
```

Output:

```
["matches: [['1.1', '1.2', 'Lord of the Day of Judgment!'], ['2.1', '2.2', 'Lord of the Day of Judgment!']]"]
```

**BEFORE EDIT:**

If your array is one dimensionel, you don't need to say column, it is just item.  Then your job is easy like you have done above. Just, you have a few syntax errors. Use this code:

```
array1 = ["1stcolumn", "2ndColumn", "1-3rdColumn"]
array2 = ["1stcolumn", "2ndColumn", "2-3rdColumn"]
array3 = []
if array1[0] == array2[0] and array1[1] == array2[1]:
       array3.append('matches: {!r}'.format(array1))
print(array3)
```

Output:

```
["matches: ['1stcolumn', '2ndColumn', '1-3rdColumn']"]
```

So, if you have any other problem, let us know.

Comment: The comparison can also be done with `array1[:2] == array2[:2]`.

Comment: My array is 2 dimensional.Both arrays have 3 columns and 4000 rows . So, how can we match with 2d array?

Comment: Yes, actually, this is a better way. But, I didn't want to change the original code much.

Comment: @Nisa I edited my answer for 2-dimesional arrays. If my answer doesn't work and your problem continue, share a part of your arrays, then let us know more details.

Comment: Thank you..But your code is checking whether number of rows are equal or not..i need to compare contents of first 2 columns of both arrays and retrieve the matching indexes and i also need to loop through all the rows of array to compare.. Here are my sample arrays: array1=[''1","4","Lord of the Day of Judgment!'']    array2=["1","4","مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ"]

Comment: Yes my code is checking whether number of rows are equal or not, because if it is not equal, you can't compare columns. After checking the equality of row numbers, the function compares content of columns in for loop. For loop is inside the function. If you you try the function with different inputs, you will see it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of errors in this code snippet which will prevent it from even running without errors.

- Python lists are declared with commas between elements. For example,
  a declaration of a list of strings could be:

  array1 = ["this", "is", "a", "list"]

  Examples of using lists in Python (3) can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).
- The Python logical 'and' operator is not &. It is `and`. See
  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485466/pythons-equivalent-of-logical-and-in-an-if-statement) question.
- In Python, as in most languages, variables must be declared before
  they can be referenced. In your code, `array3` is never declared. You
  can always declare an empty list like this:

  array3 = []

Answer (score 0):

As always we need a sample data set

```
In [1]: from random import randint

In [2]: a = [[randint(0, 1) for _ in range(3)] for __ in range(10)]

In [3]: b = [[randint(0, 1) for _ in range(3)] for __ in range(10)]
```

Have a look at it

```
In [4]: for aa, bb in zip(a, b): print(aa, bb)
[1, 1, 0] [0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0] [1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0] [0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1] [1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0] [1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1] [1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1] [1, 0, 0]
```

It seems that there are a few candidates... let's see if we can sort out the sub-lists of the first list where the first 2 elements are equal to the corresponding 
elements of the corresponding sub-list in the second list.

A possible solution involves a list comprehension, using `zip` to pair corresponding sub-lists and filtering according to our criterium:

```
In [5]: c = [aa for (aa, bb) in zip(a, b) if aa[:2]==bb[:2]]
```

where the comparison is done on two *slices* of the sub-lists, avoiding the use of the logical operator `and`.

Comparing `c` with the dump of `a` and `b` (see input cell #4)

```
In [6]: c
Out[6]: [[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]

In [7]:
```

it seems to me that the list comprehension procedure here proposed is correct.