# Python - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, operands

I am trying to write an elif condition as below:

```
if(type = a):
    do this
elif(type=b|c):
    do this
else:
    do this
```

I am getting an error for the below statement

```
elif(type=b|c)
```

Error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Could anyone advice where am I going wrong with this. Thanks

Comment: What do you think `type=b|c` does?

Comment: Possible dumplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485466/pythons-equivalent-of-logical-and-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the syntax.

```
elif(type == b or type == c):
```

or:

```
elif(type in [b, c]):
```

Comment: Assuming a, b, c are literally strings? Like type == 'int' where a is a replacement for int? That's rather confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You mean by (read comments):

```
if(type == a):
    do this
elif type in {b,c}: # i use `set` because it's the fastest # Also can do `type==b or type==c`
    do this
else:
    do this
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if(type == a):
        do this
    elif (type == b OR type == c):
        do this
    else:
        do this
```