# Am getting a Syntax error saying invalid syntax when i combine bitwise and logical operator in an if statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, operators

Below is the code, I want to the program to display something after verifying the variable status is between 0 to 20.

```
status = 12
if (status >= 0 & <= 20):
   print("something")
```

Comment: What do you think ``& <= 20`` means? Did you intend to test ``0 <= status <= 20``?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's equivalent of && (logical-and) in an if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485466/pythons-equivalent-of-logical-and-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: No i want to test if the status is in between 0 to 20. I have tried "and"  and it is not working also. The idea thoeretically is "If status is equal to or greater than 0 and equal to or less than 20 display something"

Comment: You could do `status >= 0 & status <= 20`,  or `status >= 0 and  status <= 20` or `0 <= status <= 20`

Comment: Related: [Determine Whether Integer Is Between Two Other Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13628791/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a syntax error.  Both `&` and `and` (which is the one you *should* be using) expect two expressions as operands, and `<= 20` is not a valid expression.

```
if status >= 0 and status <= 20:
```

However, *comparison* operators are parsed specially to allow for *chaining* of comparisons.

```
0 <= status <= 20
```

is not parsed as nested expressions like `(0 <= status) <= 20`

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('(0 <= status) <= 20'))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Compare(left=Compare(left=Num(n=0), ops=[LtE()], comparators=[Name(id='status', ctx=Load())]), ops=[LtE()], comparators=[Num(n=20)]))])"
```

or `0 <= (status <= 20)`

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('0 <= (status <= 20)'))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Compare(left=Num(n=0), ops=[LtE()], comparators=[Compare(left=Name(id='status', ctx=Load()), ops=[LtE()], comparators=[Num(n=20)])]))])"
```

, but as a single expression consisting of two comparison operations.

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('0 <= status <= 20'))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Compare(left=Num(n=0), ops=[LtE(), LtE()], comparators=[Name(id='status', ctx=Load()), Num(n=20)]))])"
```

The semantics are nearly identical to the semantics of `0 <= status and status <= 20`, which the difference being that `status` is only evaluated once.

---

In general, `x OP1 y OP2 z` is equivalent to `x OP1 y and y OP2 z`, where each of `OP1` and `OP2` can be one of `>`, `<`, `==`, `!=`, `>=`, `<=`, `is`, `is not`, `in`, or `not in`. Most of the combinations are less readable than an explicit conjunction of tests; stick with "natural-looking" combination like `x < y <= z`, `x < y == z`, etc.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will more into these from now on

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `&` with `and`. In python, there is no `&&`, there is only `and`. In addition, when doing the `and` operator, each side of the `and` should be a valid comparison. In the if statement, the first thing that is compared is `status >= 0`, which returns a boolean. However, in the next part of the if statement, you put `<= 20`, which wouldn't return anything, as it is not a valid comparison. Each part of the if statement should return a boolean value.  The code below should solve your problem.

```
status = 12
if status >= 0 and status <= 20:
   print("something")
```

or

```
status = 12
if 0 <= status <= 20:
   print("something")
```

Comment: *"which wouldn't return anything, as it is not a valid comparison"* - That's a confusing way to put it, cause Python raises the SyntaxError before anything gets evaluated, so talking about returning is beside the point.