# Why does not else: run when if is false?

Tags: python

```
var1 = float(input("Variable 1:"))
operator = input("Write your operator:")
if operator == "+" or "/" or "*" or "-" or "**":
    var2 = float(input("Variable 2:"))
    if operator == "+":  # Addition
        print(f"{var1} + {var2} = ")
        print(var1+var2)
    elif operator == "*":  # Multiplication
        print(f"{var1} * {var2} = ")
        print(var1 * var2)
    elif operator == "/":  # Division
        print(f"{var1} / {var2} = ")
        print(var1/var2)
    elif operator == "-":  # Subtraction
        print(f"{var1} - {var2} = ")
        print(var1 - var2)
    elif operator == "**":  # Power
        print(f"{var1} ** {var2} = ")
        print(var1 ** var2)
else:
    print("Invalid operation, enter a correct operator")
```

I have just started to programme in Python and I have decided to create a calculator that does basic mathematical operations. It is supossed to work correctly when I put the correct symbol into the "operator" variable, but when I put some random letter it does not run the command "else". Why does this happen?

Comment: Python is not English. `or` does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: You want to check whether `operator` is in a `set`: `if operator in {"+", "/", "*", "-", "**"}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's equivalent of && (logical-and) in an if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485466/pythons-equivalent-of-logical-and-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're applying the wrong logic in the code

`operator == "+" or "/" or "*" or "-" or "**"` is just comparing `operator` and `+` symbol, Ignoring rest operators

**Correct way is**

```
if operator == "+" or operator == "-" or operator == "*" or operator == "/" or operator = "**
```

**I'll implement this like**

```
if operator in ("+", "-", "*", "/", "**")
```

Comment: No, the expression is ignoring the result of `operator == "+"` because `"/"` always evaluates `True`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` operator in this case to check if the operator is correctly written by the user:

```
if operator in {"+", "/", "*", "-", "**"}:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use () for better understanding man. you can get your concept by using like this

```
if operator == ("+" or "/" or "*" or "-" or "**"):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
operator == "+" or "/"
```

will always evaluate to `True` in the `if` expression, because the second operand `"/"` will be implicitly casted to `True` (as any other non-empty string).